# Filter string based on occurrence of forward slash (/)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel file with 1000 sites URL in a column.
I want to filter rows based on occurrence of forward slash.
Here I want to filter a site names where forward slash (/) occurrence is only 5. 
So **result** would be

1. Https://test.sharepoint.com/it/basedonhistory/kite
2. Https://test.sharepoint.com/it/basedonhistory/kite1
3. Https://test.sharepoint.com/it/basedonhistory/kite2

[image]

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: Add a helper column: `=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))` and filter on that.

Comment: Or in one go in office 365 `=FILTER(A:A,LEN(A:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"/",""))=5)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility, if one doesnt have o365.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$4)/((LEN($A$1:$A$4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$4,"/","")))=5),ROW(A1))),"-")
```

[image]